# GCOV: GCDA files not generated when to many tests performed

Tags: gcov, lcov

Good morning,

I've got a problem when using GCOV within my working environment.

Gcov is working very well when I run some tests cases (up to 1000) but no gcda are generated when running more tests.

This is how I use it.

1. I compile my code with gcov flags correctly set
2. I  boot a test server containing the gcov libs, and the variables GCOV_PREFIX and GCOV__PREFIX_STRIP
3. I launch my regression on this server
4. **Once finished I stop the server and now all the gcda files are generated**
5. use lcov and genhtml to generate the test coverage and the report.

This works very well when I've got few tests to lauch (up to 1000 cases I guess), but if I run more tests, I don't get any gcda files anymore...

- I could not find any documentation on this part, is there a buffer somewhere, where all the gcdas files are stored waiting for the server to be released?
- Is it possible to parameter this setting?
- Is there any documentation on this subject somewhere?

Thanks a lot for your help.
Regards,
Thomas

Comment: The  problem was linked to my test environment...

Comment: Hi Thomas, can we please connect at any convenient time. I really need your help to understand gcov and its usage ? Please ping me on my profile: https://www.facebook.com/pankajgangwar